# How to skip a step in spring batch based on job execution decider and continue to anothe decider?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job that downloads a set of files and steps for each file to parse them if it is downloaded. The succeeding steps are executed if the previous steps are executed however the job stops as soon as it encounters a decider return value that is not `COMPLETED`. For example below, if fileB is not downloaded, the job stops. My goal is step c and the next steps should still be evaluated.

```
public Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(downloadAllFilesStep())
            .next(isFileDownloadedDecider("fileA")).on("COMPLETED").to(parseFileAStep())
            .next(isFileDownloadedDecider("fileB")).on("COMPLETED").to(parseFileBStep())
            .next(isFileDownloadedDecider("fileC")).on("COMPLETED").to(parseFileCStep())
            ...
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

How to configure the job flow that if the decider returns not `COMPLETED` it just proceed to the next decider and so on?

Answer (score 0):

So my question very similar to this [How to skip a step execution from beforeStep method in StepExecutionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61999433/6181118). I tried the `Decider` and `beforeStep` approach but it still doesn't do my expected behavior.

My workaround for this, is if the file has not been downloaded, I just replace it with the default/mock file with no data just the headers so that it's corresponding step will instantiate then complete with no data read/processed/written. This way the step will succeed and proceed to the next.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can probably tweak your decider to return different state for the different files

```
   if(isFileACompleted){
           return new FlowExecutionStatus("FILEA_COMPLETED");
   }else {
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("FILEB_COMPLETED");
   }
```

2. Update your job method to use flow

```
public Job job() {
    FlowBuilder<Flow> fileParseFlowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>("fileParseFlow");
    Flow fileParseFlow = fileParseFlowBuilder.
         start(isFileDownloadedDecider).
                on("FILEA_COMPLETED").
                to(parseFileAStep).
         from(isFileDownloadedDecider).
                on("FILEB_COMPLETED").
                to(parseFileBStep).
                end();
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(downloadAllFilesStep())
            .next(fileParseFlow)
            ...
            .end()
            .build();
}
```